# How to calculate the refractive index of mixtures?

Tags: physical-chemistry, optical-properties

In ["How to Calculate the Refractive Index of a Formulation"](https://sciencing.com/calculate-refractive-index-formulation-7502784.html), the article outlines a method to find the refractive index of a mixture but the sources don't lead to any *evidence* regarding its validity. I would like to know the name of the formula used and if it has any limitations because I haven't been able to find any techniques to calculate the refractive index of non-binary mixtures other than this article.

Comment: Well, obviously, this is just a crude approximation.

Comment: The link in [this earlier answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19963/is-the-refractive-index-of-a-solution-of-four-substances-is-a-median-of-the-four/19968#19968) may be helpful.

Comment: This is just a weighted average, also known as the rule of mixtures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the refractive index of a solution of four substances is a median of the four subtances' refractive index?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19963/is-the-refractive-index-of-a-solution-of-four-substances-is-a-median-of-the-four)